# NoClassDefFoundError: StudentRegistrar

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror

I'm getting errors in my code and I've been banging my head against this for a few hours.  Any thoughts.... There are two java files in this Application and a DB.properties file.  Right now the program isn't supposed to do anything other than test the connection to the database.  If I missed something, please forgive me as I am new to Java.

**StudentRegistrar.java**

```
package studentregistrar;


import java.io.File;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
public class StudentRegistrar {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{


    // TODO code application logic here
    System.out.println(args);
    System.out.println(args.length);
    if (args.length == 0)
    {
        System.out.println("Usage: java -classpath driver_class_path" 
                + File.pathSeparator 
                + ".  Test DB.properties");
        return;
    }
    else
        SimpleDataSource.init(args[0]);

    Connection conn = SimpleDataSource.getConnection();
    try
    {
        Statement stat = conn.createStatement();

        stat.execute("CREATE TABLE Test (Name CHAR(20))");
        stat.execute("INSERT INTO Text VALUES ('Romeo')");

        ResultSet result = stat.executeQuery("Select * FROM Test");
        result.next();
        stat.execute("DROP TABLE Test");
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.close();
    }
}
}
```

**SimpleDataSource.java**

```
package studentregistrar;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Properties;


public class SimpleDataSource {

public static void init(String filename)
        throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
{
    Properties props = new Properties();
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(filename);
    props.load(in);
    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    url = props.getProperty("jdbc.url");
    username = props.getProperty("jdbc.username");
    if (username == null) username = "";
    password = props.getProperty("jdbc.password");
    if (password == null) password = "";
    if(driver != null)
        Class.forName(driver);
} 

public static Connection getConnection()
        throws SQLException
{
    return DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
}

private static String url;
private static String username;
private static String password;

}
```

**DB.properties**

```
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/registrar
jdbc.username=root
jdbc.password=notmypassword
jdbc.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

I compile the application in NetBeans and from what I can tell I run the command

```
 java -class driver_class_path:. StudentRegistrar DB.properties
```

And I get the Following errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: StudentRegistrar
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: StudentRegistrar
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
Could not find the main class: StudentRegistrar.  Program will exit.
```

What Am I Doing WRONG!!!  I'm sure it's something stupid.

Thanks for your time.
Kevsteelio

Comment: what errors or exceptions u r getting

Comment: Aren't package names case sensetive

Comment: What about `java -class driver_class_path:. studentregistrar.StudentRegistrar DB.properties`

Comment: The problem here has exactly *nothing to do with connecting to a database.* or MySQL either.

Answer (score 1):

You need to adjust the path.

First find where the StudentRegistrar.class exists. It must be some where like

```
<path to somefolder>/studentregistrar/StudentRegistrar.class
```

Include that `< folder>` into your class path. (The delimiters in classpath is platform specific. `:` for unix like and `;` windows)

Answer (score -1):

Use this class to connect each time

```
package pack1;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
/**
 *
 * @author Ali
 */
  class Connect {

    Connection con = null;
    public Connect() {
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database";
        String user = "user"; // defaultnya adalah root
        String pass = "****";// sesuaikan dengan konfigurasi saat install
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);

             System.out.print("connecté à la base!");
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
        public Connection getCon() {
        return con;
    }
        public Connection crtst() {
        return con;
    }
}
```

in a test class

```
     Connection con = new Connect().getCon();
             try{
      Statement st = con.createStatement();
      int val = st.executeUpdate("INSERT employee VALUES("+13+","+"'Aman'"+")");
      System.out.println("1 row affected");
      }
      catch (SQLException s){
      System.out.println("SQL statement is not executed!");
      }
```

http://www.roseindia.net/jdbc/jdbc-mysql/InsertValues.shtml

Answer (score -1):

How to run in command line:

Note:  SimpleDataSource.java, StudentRegistrar.java and mysql driver (jar) in the same directory from where you are running the following commands

```
In Windows
compile: 
javac -cp .;mysql_driver_jar SimpleDataSource.java
javac StudentRegistrar.java

run:
java -cp .;mysql_driver_jar StudentRegistrar DB.properties

In Unix
Compile:
javac -cp .:mysql_driver_jar SimpleDataSource.java
javac StudentRegistrar.java

run:
java -cp .:mysql_driver_jar StudentRegistrar DB.properties
```

Comment: No. It's in a package. Little or none of his will work.